# Get the row which cannot be Inserted into SQL server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of around 800+ columns and 150 rows. Each row data is for one file.

[image: :Filename |column1|.......|column800|: :file1.xlsx|1. |.......| a :file2.xlsx|2. |.......| b]

.....150 rows.

I am inserting this data into Microsoft SQL server using an INSERT query.

My problem is if even one row has an error none of the other rows gets inserted. The errors arise mainly because of datatype issues, and it is impossible to verify which column (among 800+) has the error.

I want to store the files, which cannot be inserted into SQL in a list and continue with the insertion of the other files.

Below is a psuedo code of what I am trying to achieve in python:

```
for i,j in df.iterrows():

INSERT INTO SQL TABLE(Filename, column1,...,column800) values(?,?,....?) 
i.filename,
i.column1
...
i.column800

if INSERT INTO throws an error/warning:
error_file_list = i.filename
else:
continue inserting
```

Can someone help me with this, with a code or anything?

Thanks!

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: you can use **try - except**.  And why not use df.to_sql() instead of loop? Also do not use **[iterrows()](https://ryxcommar.com/2020/01/15/for-the-love-of-god-stop-using-iterrows/)** it's very slow.

Comment: df.to_sql did not work for me, for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python / cx_Oracle, you can use executemany with batcherror = True, for example :

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(
   user="me", 
   password="userpwd",
   dsn="dbhost.example.com/orclpdb1"
)

curs = conn.cursor()

query = 'insert into my_test_table values (:1, :2, :3)'
params = [['a', 1, "toto"],
          ['b', 2, "tata"],
          ['c', 3, 06215]
          ]

curs.executemany(query, params, batcherrors=True)
for error in curs.getbatcherrors():
    log.error(f"{error.message} at row offset {error.offset}")
    log.error(f"line not inserted: {params[error.offset]}")
```

See documentation here : https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#handling-data-errors

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server, but thanks I will give this a go